# Row in ListView not getting highlighted when clicked on

Tags: winforms

I have a WinForms ListView displaying several rows. When I click on any row, the row doesn't get highlighted with  blue color. I am not sure why this is happening.
I had an event handler for the mouseclick and I took that off. I had a popmenu menu and took that off. HideSelection is set to true. Enabled is true.  (VS 2013)

Any ideas what might cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the [ListView.FullRowSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect(v=vs.110).aspx) property is set to true.